# How to solve Index out of bounds error?

Tags: python, ipython, astronomy

I'm a bit confused on an error I keep running into. I didn't have it before, but at the same time my data was wrong so I had to re-write the code.

Running the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
x = np.arange(1416, 1426, 0.009766)

gaverage = np.empty((21,1024), dtype = np.float64)

calibdata = open(pathc + 'calib_5m.dat').readlines()

#print(np.size(calibdata))     ||| Yields: 624
#print(np.size(calibdata)//16) ||| Yields: 39

calib = np.empty(shape=(np.size(calibdata)//16,1024), dtype=np.float64)
for i in range(0, np.size(calibdata)//4):
    calib[i] = calibdata[i*4+3].split()
caverage = np.average(calib[i] ,axis = 0)
```

Yields this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-87f3f4739851> in <module>()
     11 calib = np.empty(shape=(np.size(calibdata)//16,1024), dtype=np.float64)
     12 for i in range(0, np.size(calibdata)//4):
---> 13     calib[i] = calibdata[i*4+3].split()
     14 caverage = np.average(calib[i] ,axis = 0)
     15 

IndexError: index 39 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 39
```

Now what I'm trying to do here is basically take every 4th line in the file read in calibdata and write it to a new array, calib[i]. If the indices are the same size how are they out of bounds? I think there's some fundamentally flawed logic here on my part so if anyone can point out where I'm falling short, that would be great.

Comment: when i is calibdata // 4 it is 156 so i*4+3 is 627 which will read beyond the end of calibdata.

Comment: so I think you need  for i in range(0, np.size(calibdata)//4 - 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calib` is initialized to size (39,n).  But `i` iterator goes well beyond that:

```
In [243]: for i in range(np.size(calibdata)//4):
     ...:     print(i, i*4+3)
     ...:     
0 3
1 7
2 11
3 15
4 19
5 23
6 27
7 31
8 35
....
147 591
148 595
149 599
150 603
151 607
152 611
153 615
154 619
155 623

In [244]: calib=np.zeros((np.size(calibdata)//16),int)
In [245]: calib.shape
Out[245]: (39,)
```